# Retrofit GET method error Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new to Retrofit . i am trying to call api using base url,but i getting  error  while loading function.there is a object and inside that there is two different arrays name animal and birds.i need to call this array from the object and need to load in gridview adapter. 
this is how i calling the function in my fragment.

```
 My error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.
    for method GetDataService.getAll
```

1. This is my JSON response

   ```
   {
      "animals": [
      {
         "animalName": "String",
         "animalID": "integer",

   }

    ],
       "birds": [
     {
       "birdsId": "integer",
       "birdsname": "string
    }

   ],

    "ID": "integer"
   }
   ```
2. Calling GET in fragment

   ```
   Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
           .baseUrl("http://demoapp.in/")
           .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
           .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
           .build();

   GetDataService service = retrofit.create(GetDataService .class);
   Call<TableResponse> call= service.getAll(new TableResponse());
   call.enqueue(new Callback<TableResponse>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<TableResponse> call, Response<TableResponse> response) {

           String passKey = response.body().getPassKey();
           List<Table> TableName = response.body().getTables();
           String[] TableNameArray = new String[TableName.size()];
           for (int i = 0; i < TableName.size(); i++) {

               TableNameArray[i] = TableName.get(i).getTableName();

           }

           gridView.setAdapter(new TableViewAdapter(getContext(), TableNameArray));

       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<TableResponse> call, Throwable t) {

       }
   });
   ```

3.TableResponse,java class in this fie is generated using jsonschema2pojo

```
@SerializedName("animal")
@Expose
private List<Table> animal = null;
   ......
  public TableResponse(){
    this.animal= animal;
    this.birds= birds;
    this.ID = ID;
   }


public List<Table> getTables() {
    return tables;
}

  -------
```

4.GetDataService.java

```
@GET("Animal.ashx")
Call<TableResponse> getAll(@Body TableResponse tableResponse);
```

Comment: did you try change Call<TableResponse> getAll(@Body TableResponse tableResponse) to  Call<TableResponse> getAll()?

Comment: when you pass parameters as @Body it not template of GET

Comment: @CôngHải  while calling this fumction Call<TableResponse> getAll()  error is gone but it didnt fetching data

Comment: Is your get api need parammeter?

Comment: Show me your get url to achieve your json

Comment: @CôngHải there is no paramenter to load url

Comment: @sherin you can't have body payload when using get request, body is only used in Post/Put request

Comment: @CôngHải ,mangkool  i updated my code with @POST("Animal.ashx")
Call<TableResponse> getAll();

Answer (score -1):

`@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")`

`@GET("helper-url")`

`fun getHelperUrl(`

`@Query("api_token") apiToken: String,`

`@Query("authtype") authType: String,`

`@Query("channel") channel: String`

`): Call<ResponseHelperUrl>`

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update you answer.